# Saving Serializers with Foreign Key (django rest framework)

Tags: javascript, django, django-rest-framework

I have two models which is `Task` and `Batch` that are related to each other by Foreign Key field. When creating a `Task Object`, I want to check first if a `Batch Object` is available in database (batch is just the current date, so I can group each task using batch). If not, create a Batch object and then pass the newly created batch object to the Task that is being created.

The problem is, when I am saving a data, I am getting an error:

`(index):328 POST http://localhost:8000/api/task-create/ 500 (Internal Server Error)`

views.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def taskCreate(request):
    batch = Batch.objects.filter(batch = datetime.date.today()).first()
    serializer = TaskSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save(commit=False)
        if batch is None :
            batch = Batch.objects.create(batch = datetime.date.today())
        serializer.batch = batch
        serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

models.py

```
class Batch(models.Model):
    batch = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-batch']
        verbose_name = 'Batch'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Batches'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.batch.strftime("%B %d, %Y %A")

class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(
            max_length = 256,
        )
    completed = models.BooleanField(
            default =  False,
        )
    batch = models.ForeignKey(Batch, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

serializers.py

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1
```

this is how I handle my form in frontend:

```
        var form = document.getElementById("form")
        form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault()
            var url = "{% url 'api:task-create' %}"
            if(activeItem != null ){
                url = `http://localhost:8000/api/task-update/${activeItem.id}/`
                activeItem = null
            }
            var title = document.getElementById('title').value
            fetch(url, {

                method: 'POST',
                headers:{
                    'Content-type': 'application/json',
                    'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({'title':title})
            }).then(function(response){
                renderList()
                document.getElementById('form').reset()
            })
        })
```

Comment: can you provide a JSON example to the data that you pass in the request?

Comment: also, add your full error trace

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: found the answer myself

views.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def taskCreate(request):
    check_batch = Batch.objects.filter(batch = datetime.date.today()).first()
    if check_batch is None:
        check_batch = Batch.objects.create(batch = datetime.date.today())
    serializer = TaskSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save(batch = check_batch)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

and I access the foreing key data on vanilla js with:

```
${taskList[task].batch.batch}
```